# Your recommendation to reset a postgress database in heroku after CircleCI tests

Tags: python, heroku, circleci

I am using Circle CI for tests and pushing a python application to heroku in order to also run Web GUI tests on the machine.

What is your recommended way of filling up the heroku instance with a certain database content?

I do not think that circle CI should access the heroku instance or the database directly?

The heroku deploy hooks only seem to be able to call a web hook. But I would like to run a command to reset the database.

Comment: Are you using Heroku Postgres? Also, are we talking about a dev-only database that you want to erase completely, or just resetting it to a known state? If you're using Heroku Postgres you can drop all the database contents with [`heroku pg:reset HEROKU_COLOR_POSTGRES_URL --confirm your_app_name`.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in heroku deployments, you won't be able to do this, e.g. if your configuration looks like this:

```
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master
    heroku:
      appname: foo-bar-123
```

You can instead configure your deployment to run several commands:

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: production
    commands:
      - "[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
      - git push git@heroku.com:foo-bar-123.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app foo-bar-123:
          timeout: 400 # if your deploys take a long time
```

The comment from Two-Bit Alchemist would be a good command to reset the database.

The above examples are taken from: https://circleci.com/docs/continuous-deployment-with-heroku#heroku-setup